# Change 'Return to Shop' URL to the previous page in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, code-snippets

I have the following snippet to which redirects the 'Return to Shop' button on an empty cart page to a specific URL:

```
function wc_empty_cart_redirect_url() {
    return 'https://xxxxx.com/xxxx/';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'wc_empty_cart_redirect_url' );
```

However, I'd really like to have it return the user to the previous page they were on, as if they were hitting the back button on their browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_referer`. try below code.

```
function wc_empty_cart_redirect_url() {
    return wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : 'https://xxxxx.com/xxxx/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'wc_empty_cart_redirect_url' );
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately that didn't work.  It just stays on the empty cart page when clickied.